# posting data in curl command dynamically

Tags: bash, post, curl

The following curl command works fine in shell script

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{ "param1": "one", "param2": "two"}' http://mysite
```

However if try to pass the -d parameter dynamically then it does't work.
For e.g

```
data="{\"param1\":\"one\", \"param2\": \"two\"}"
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d "$data" http://mysite
```

The above curl command fails.

I know it can be done with files however I don't want to use that

Comment: The command fails how? What is the error message?

Comment: Error message is: Http/1.1 500 Server Error

Comment: Is it your site? Then look in the server's error log to see what went wrong.

Comment: The value of `data` in your second example is slightly different than the string you passed in the first example. The differences appear to only be whitespace, but perhaps it matters to whatever process is parsing that data on the server.

Comment: Is that the real way you're assigning `data`, or are you building it dynamically from some other variables? I suspect the problem is there.

Comment: What does `echo "$data"` show?

Comment: echo $data shows {"param1":"one", "param2": "two"}

Comment: If you use the **exact** string from the first example as the right-hand side of the `data=...` assignment in the second example does it still fail?